# Authentication token in React.js

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt

I want to set the authenticate token as a key-value pair in a react-js like **x-access-token(key) = JWToken.value**

I am generating the token like following in the backend:

```
module.exports = middlewares = {
  authenticateToken: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      if (
        !req.headers["x-access-token"] ||
        req.headers["x-access-token"] === ""
      ) {
        return res.failed(401, "Key x-access-token not found");
      }

      const token = req.headers["x-access-token"];
      const data = jwt.verify(token, keys.JWToken);
      if (!data) return res.failed(401, "Invalid token");
      req.data = data;

      next();
    } catch (error) {
      return res.failed(500, "Internal server error", error);
    }
  },
};
```

How can I do that because whenever I send the request to the protected route I am getting the Unauthorized error which is obvious.

the data stored in the local storage:

```
{flag: true, code: 200, data: ..., message: "Logged in successfully", error: null}
code : 200
data : 
   JWToken : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzMjQ9MzRjOTQxNTMxMTYzZDIwMDFhYSIsImlhdCO8MTY2xzgzMjcyNywiZXhwIjoxMjk1Mzg5NjUzfQ.JOO1Cy8-7M4_kFHxRyK6g48s9vR2xXSB3pOpAzw3UgS"
   user : {_id: "6324734c941531163d2001aa", email: "John@test.com", phone_number: "1334567891"}
     email : "John@test.com"
     is_verified : true
     role : "admin"
     _id : "6324734c941531163d2001aa"
     error : null
     flag : true
     message : "Logged in successfully"
```

The package action file:

```
export const createPackage = (packageData) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PACKAGE_CREATE_REQUEST });

    const {
      adminLogin: { adminInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `${adminInfo.data.JWToken}`,
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:8000/v1/package/add_package",
      packageData,
      config
    );
    dispatch({ type: PACKAGE_CREATE_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PACKAGE_CREATE_FAILURE,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you using axios to send requests from react?

Comment: Yes, I am using axios @DrashtiKheni

Comment: Can you please add that code?

Comment: Are you sure that `adminInfo.data.JWToken` this is not undefined or has some value?

Comment: yes I am sure that it has a value of token. It is not undefined. @DrashtiKheni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try once like this?

```
const config = {
    url: "http://localhost:8000/v1/package/add_package",
    method: "POST",
    data: packageData,
    headers: {
      "x-access-token": adminInfo.data.JWToken,
    }
  };
const { data } = await axios(config).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Actually, I am not using **bearer token** here. I am using key-value pair. like x-access-token is the key and value will be the token value. With bearer token I know how to do that.